# Prove that $\mathbb{Z ×Z}/\langle(4, 12)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z×Z_4}$

Tags: group-theory

I am confused with this question because $\langle(4, 12)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ hence $\mathbb{Z×Z/\langle(4,12)\rangle}$  is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}$.

What am I doing wrong. Kindly tell me that and how to prove the problem

Comment: The issue is that modding out by a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ won't necessarily "cancel" one of the $\mathbb{Z}$'s. For example, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, yet $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 5):

Your line of thinking would also produce the following:

> $2ℤ$ is isomorphic to $ℤ$, so $ℤ/2ℤ$ is isomorphic to $ℤ/ℤ = 0$.

The problem is that “For $B, C ⊆ A$ with $B \cong C$ we have $A/B \cong A/C$” is wrong and there is no reason why it should be true: An isomorphism $B → C$ need not extend to an automorphism of $A$. And in general, there are many different isomorphic substructures of a structure $A$ that can lie in all sorts of ways in it, each producing different factor structures.

What you need to do is find an automorphism $ℤ × ℤ → ℤ × ℤ$ that maps $0 × 4ℤ$ onto $⟨4,12⟩$.

*Hint*. Think of $ℤ × ℤ$ as columns and try to find an invertible matrix $A ∈ \operatorname{Mat}_{2×2}(ℤ)$, mapping $[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{smallmatrix}]$ to $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{smallmatrix}]$. Then project and conclude with the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1=(1,3)$ and $v_2=(0,1)$. Then $v_1,v_2$ form a basis for $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ since $e_1=v_1-3v_2$ and $e_2=v_2$.

Since $(4, 12)= 4v_2$, we get
$$
\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{\langle(4, 12)\rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z v_1 \oplus \mathbb Z v_1}{0\mathbb Z v_1  \oplus 4\mathbb Z v_2}
\cong
\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_4
$$